# How can I halt the spread of corruption after winning hell?

Tags: terraria

After defeating the Wall of Flesh, corruption is spreading much faster and bypasses sunflowers. Are there any other methods of halting it than hallowing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save the world from both good and evil corruption?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/how-can-i-save-the-world-from-both-good-and-evil-corruption)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe a Hallowed Biome will prevent them from spreading. These can be created by planting Hallowed Seeds, which are gained by smashing a Demon Altar with a PwnHammer.

Edit: I've discovered I was mistaken about how to get Hallowed Seeds. You don't directly get them from the Demon Altar, but instead buy them from the Dryad after smashing the altar.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing; entirely hallowed surface FTW!

Comment: That's what I'm working on right now, but I've planted corrupted seeds on a couple of my flying islands, in case I want something from corruption.

Answer (score 9):

You just gotta make sure the Corruption is contained (i.e., has nothing to spread to). Any Corrupted block can spread via these blocks:

- Exposed Dirt and Grass
- Stone
- Sand
- Jungle Grass
- Mud

Additionally, it can [jump up to three blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40158/in-hardmode-how-large-of-a-gap-can-hallow-corruption-cross) (that is, clear 2-wide gaps). Therefore, digging a trench lined with incorruptible materials should stop it. However, preserving the natural biome isn't very practical in the long run, for several reasons:

- The Corruption can spread underground via the abundant Stone, and possibly tunnel under your trenches and corrupt everything in a heartbeat.
- Corrupted grass can develop thorns, which could reach across your trenches and start corrupting.

Creating a [Hallowed biome](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/The_Hallow) really is your best bet against the Corruption. It spreads just like the Corruption, but they cancel each other out. Corrupt blocks will not infect hallowed ones and vice versa.

It's still rather dangerous to be in, but I believe it is the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, you can stop Corruption with the following methods:

1. If you need to keep corruption away from your housing, you could 'dome' the house with a non-corruptible material such as Clay, Glass, any ores, bricks, etc. Note, though, that your dome must be 4 blocks across or corruption can go to the other side.
2. If you need a quick temporary fix, you *Can* buy a lot of Purification Powder from the Dryad and purify your corruption, which will slow it.
3. If you want to somewhat cheat, I think [Tshock](http://tshock.co/xf/) has the ability to convert corruption to normal blocks.
4. If you have access to the [Steampunker](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Steampunker) you can buy the Clentaminator and Green Solution. However, this is very expensive and requires you to defeat a Hardmode Boss to spawn the Steampunker.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Corruption or Crimson can get past a mushroom biome. If you have a jungle nearby that you want to preserve, purchase some dark blue solution from the shroomite, dig a hole down to the underworld, and line both sides with the dark blue solution using the clentaminator. mushroom biomes don't spread, so it acts as a static wall between your jungle and the corruption/crimson.

I've found that simply keeping a clentaminator with me at all times is the best way to go about getting items; if I need a specific biome, I simply create one right around me. I most commonly use this when I need a pure (non hallow non corrupt) underground area.

Answer (score -2):

If you play on an Xbox or PlayStation, you can make a wall of dirt separating the corruption/crimson from the forest and plant Hallowed seeds. The hallow will eventually take over the corruption/crimson. Although the hallow is very dangerous as well as the corruption and crimson, it's a way to make your world less evil.