# In hardmode, how large of a gap can hallow/corruption cross?

Tags: terraria

After destroying the Wall of flesh, the corruption and new hallow start to spread aggressively. I've noticed that they can spread across air gaps and (I think) past terrain they can't assimilate. How large of a space can they cross?

Related Question: [How can I halt the spread of corruption after winning hell?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/how-can-i-halt-the-spread-of-corruption-after-winning-hell)

Comment: I'm certain that hallow, at least, can't cross a three blocks high gap, as in, a horizontal tunnel trough a hill can create some kind of grass island in the middle of the hallow.

Comment: @Jupotter I've only seen it cross a 2 block wide vertical tunnel, which makes me think you're right, but it's possible that the horizontal jump distance is different from the vertical (and bigger than 2). Also, I could see there being a difference in the vertical jump distance if the hallow is above the grass due to vines hanging down or just sheer cussedness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Corruption, Crimson, and Hallow can jump up to three blocks to affect other blocks, and Corruption and Crimson can spread farther by using vines. You can prevent them from doing so by digging a 4 block wide channel. You may be able to leave it empty, but if you have trouble with corrupted vines, you may need to stop them with blocks that cannot be converted, such as Ash, Bricks, or Wood.

Comment: This question is about the hardmode Corruption (and Hallow), for which this is definitely not true. I've seen Pearlstone clear a 2-block gap (as in, while I was looking at it).

Comment: Wow. Alright. I haven't actually gotten to hardmode yet, so I'm just going by what I've read. I'll be getting to that point tonight :D

Comment: Found some more information for you.

Comment: Stone is a bad idea as it can also be corrupted. Any kind of bricks is safe fro corruption.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Why did you revert my edit? As it stands, the answer is misleading, because the first and second paragraph contradict each other, unless one looks at the comments.

Comment: @Fritz Corruption can clear gaps before hard mode just like after hard mode.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer But then the first paragraph is plain wrong. In Hardmode, it can cross gaps just like that, without any vines. However, the first paragraph says it can't.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, the corruption, crimson, and hallow, can spread to any corruptible block up to 3 blocks away, so a three block gap  should be sufficient to stop spread. If you are blocking surface crimson/corruption, you should fill the gap up with non corruptible blocks (only from the underground crimson/corruption (the music will change) to the surface) to stop vines/thorny bushes, or just line it with any block that doesnt produce them, such as crim/ebonstone (make sure to keep the 3 block gap tho)