# Will the corruption/hallow be able to jump across my shaft?

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In hardmode, how large of a gap can hallow/corruption cross?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40158/in-hardmode-how-large-of-a-gap-can-hallow-corruption-cross)

I understand that this question has been asked loads of time, but all the forums, wikis and answers I am seeing give different answers, so I am confused in regard to what and what not the corruption/hallow is able to jump across.

[image]

That picture asks my question. But, to add a bit more, I understand that there are also other factors (such as corruptors, the infection from other directions), that might cause this area to become infected. Lets forget about those factors, all I am asking is if the corruption/hallow will be able to jump across *this* shaft.

Comment: The corruption can't ignore your shaft Jesus :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in [Hardmode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode#Biomes):

> Corruption and Hallow will spread to stone, sand and dirt that are up to three tiles away.

and

> Almost all other blocks are immune to Corruption and Hallow, including Wood, Clay Blocks, Ash Blocks, Silt Blocks, Obsidian, Ores, Gems, and all bricks (except Pearlstone, which will spread Hallow).

The tunnel in your screenshot appears to be three blocks wide *and* lined with bricks.  This essentially means there is a 5 block barrier between the spreadable blocks.

**I deem your tunnel safe!**

Just be careful to ensure uniform width of your tunnel.  Also, watch out for  [Corruptors](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Corruptor).  Prior to version 1.2, their projectiles may spread Corruption if they hit a corruptible tile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1. I'm just going to wait a bit to see what other people have to say before I accept anything. Also HAHA :D

Comment: Another thing to watch for with Corruptor spit is that if it hits non-corruptible blocks near corruptible ones, the AoE can still effect the corruptible blocks.

Comment: This is outdated, Corruptors no longer spread Corruption.

Comment: @TrangOul This information has been updated