# How can I save the world from the spread of Hallow and Corruption/Crimson?

Tags: terraria

After the Wall of Flesh, the Hallow appears and Corruption/Crimson spreads even faster.

- Corruption/Crimson spreads through everything

  - Except Hallow
- Hallow spreads through everything

  - Except mud (jungle)
  - Except synthetic blocks like gray-brick
- The results of Hallow and Corruption meeting are unpredictable

How can I stop them both permanently and effectively from taking over the world, considering both the top layer and underground?

(Eg, simply placing gray brick on top of the surface won't stop the underground spread?)

And, is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the Clentaminator present in the game, this is actually quite easy, if a bit time consuming and expensive. Dig hellevators every 120 blocks across the area you want to purify. With the Green Solution equipped, float down the each hellevator twice, first spraying to the left, then to the right. I recently did this in one of my worlds, and it worked perfectly. I'd recommend checking every so often after you're done to make sure you didn't miss anything. This will also turn any underground mushroom biome to jungle, so you may want to go back when you're done and convert it back with Dark Blue Solution.

When I did this, I left large swathes of land from the surface to the underworld converted, and even brought in Crimson from another world so I had all the biomes present. Just make sure that if you do this you put wider shafts (I left six blocks) around the corrupted/crimsoned/hallowed areas so they don't spread.

Comment: As an alternative to gridding it out, if one had enough cash, one could always just dynamite the everloving *crap* out of it.  ^.^

Comment: Well, yes, but I assumed he wanted to purify the land, not just destroy it :P

Comment: I just don't want it to take up ALL the world, as the wiki says that eventually it will O_O

Comment: Does the background-wall also need to be removed, or just the normal blocks/stone/dirt/whatever ?

Comment: While it's prohibitively difficult to isolate the hallow and corruption from the rest of the world, it's not so difficult to isolate a part of the surface as a nature preserve.

Comment: Just the normal stone and grass.

Comment: @rlb.usa The background wall, if left, will become corrupted, but as far as I have seen through some rather accidental testing, the background wall will not spread corruption (or hallow, etc.) back onto foreground blocks.

Comment: So it's possible to cleanse a world of corruption just by mining it?

Comment: @Thomas That's... actually a good question. I'm curious what the druid would say if you removed every block from the world.

Comment: I mined out a pretty good section of corruption in one of my worlds and it didn't change her percentages at all. But I may not have mined enough, as much as I thought I mined.

Comment: Confirmed: You *can* mine corruption to cleanse the world. After spending a good amount of time wiping out all of the corruption in one area, the Dryad's status went from 10% to 6%. It does take some time for her status to update, both numbers were given to me after I finished mining, but one was about 5 minutes after the other.

Answer (score 9):

Ever since the 1.2 update, the NPC steampunker (gained by killing a mechanical boss) sells the Clentaminator (for 2 platinum coins).

This used with green solution (25 silver) as the ammo will return anything it hits back to the purity (normal grasslands).

It has a range of about 40 so you can make tunnels every 80 blocks and spray in both directions.

Answer (score 6):

Pre-hardmode, your best bet is probably to limit the 'inconvenience' of Corrupted turf, and latter surgically remove areas of severe risk, before summoning and defeating the Wall of Flesh boss (activating Hardmode and the rapid spread of corruption/Hallow).

What I do is to chop down all trees (and remove any chests sitting on grass) in a corrupted area, and then beat the tar out of any and all grass (and thorns) on any exposed surface. I then brick over the entrances to the Chasm, and sprinkle Purification Powder on exposed Ebonstone (Vile/Purification Powders normalize, Holy/Unholy Waters convert a target to the extremes). What ends up happening is that generally, foot traffic through these 'tame' Corrupt areas tends to get interrupted much less by Corruption beasts (with the exception of the occasional Devourer), as most of the "Eater" creatures tend to have to come from the bottom edge of the screen, and get trapped inside their pits.

At this point, I mainly visit the Chasm for Shadow Orb breaking, and collecting Vile Mushrooms (and ripe Deathweed during Blood Moon, until I get enough seeds for a farm). On each visit, I dust the walls/floors with a stack or two of powder. Eventually, when it looks like most of the surface area in a section is pure, I dig down through the pit wall or chasm floor/ceiling, looking for any remaining ebonstone to nix, or corrupt grass spots to pound out. I flatten the surface to make fighting summoned Eater of Worlds bosses easy.

I advise that if you go about 'removing' Corruption, you take your time and do it before you go Hardmode, so that you don't have to do it all in one long, tedious run to avoid a relapse. Even then, I haven't really played into Hardmode yet, so I can't say how drastically you'll have to revise this strategy when it's triggered.

Generally speaking, there's enough clay or unexposed dirt in most strata of the underground's upper layers that you needn't fear needing to blow up the whole world. Remove corrupted/hallowed grass from as much of the surface (and surface caves/pools) as you can, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't that big of a deal to be honest. Depending on which mode you are playing, you should be able to beat the game before the percentage of corruption hits 20%. And if you really don't want your world becoming fully corruption/crimson, you can just dig a three block wide tunnel with wooden blocks on either side, around your houses.

Answer (score -1):

One way to fight(not totally fix the problem unless you are very devoted) is to use vile/purification powder on hallow/corruption blocks respectively. These powders will turn the blocks into regular blocks, though if you take too long to purify the world it may make no difference

Comment: Really? When I was reading the wiki it thought it said doing this merely turned it into whatever powder you poured (eg, corruption poured with hallow powder turns into hallow?). Maybe I misread. Just wanted to check.

Comment: @rlb.usa — I haven't verified it myself, but my understanding is that you convert hallow to corruption via vile powder and convert corruption to "normal" via purification powder.

Comment: i just snagged this information from the terraria wiki. http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Vile_Powder says near the bottom that it was added in 1.1 that corruption powder removes hallow. whether or not this information is true, i don't have access to terraria right now to check.

Comment: It doesn't change it to the other. It just removes it.

Comment: my friend was really ticked off by both stones, then we got the hamdrax and all of our problems were solved

Answer (score -1):

Get purification powder from your town Dryad. It depends on how much corruption you have to determine how much purification you will need. As far as I know corruption can't spread through dirt so as long as you spread it along the top of the grass and maybe in some chasms if needed you can slowly get rid of it day by day. Try to get rid of most corruption before hardmode, otherwise Corruptors will come and spread more corruption, basically reversing the whole cause. However, if the corruption has already spread a decent amount through a fairly large cave you are most likely hopeless unless you have a ton of bombs/grenades/dynamite

Comment: But grenades cannot destroy blocks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in late game, I suggest getting the rocket launcher (not the snowman cannon due to its homing) and rocket IV, which is sold for 5 silver each during a solar eclipse, or rocket 2, sold for 2 silver 50 copper during a blood moon, the clentaminator from the steampunker for 2 platinum, and green solution (for clentaminator). DISCLAIMER this is recommended if you are as bent on it as me. If not, then biuld a space city (all the npcs will negate most spawning).

Answer (score -2):

I downloaded Scooterboot's Metroid Mod. Within it I was able to build a weapon that launches missiles that explode tiles.  There's also a few other perks.

It takes forever, but is better than sprinkling magic peter pan powder everywhere.

Blow it all up, save the dirt so that you can craft the landscape at your preference.

Comment: Magic Peter Pan powder :D

Answer (score -2):

As a cheaper answer to corruption you can always go into "my documents/my games/terraria/players" and copy ALL FILES for one player and go back in and out of the game double your purification powder or bombs (or even money) cheating, yes but makes it a little less frustrating.

Although I would more go for the method of mining either side then bomb the middle and build either a platform or bridge over the top.

Answer (score -2):

I'm in the process of getting rid of corruption and I find that a mix of powder and explosives work well. However in Hardmode if you want to get your world corrupt free you will need a second player otherwise you're screwed.

Answer (score -3):

It is not worth trying to remove it in your world. make a new world transfer your stuff and use a world with very little corruption. Then just live there until the corruption spreads. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score -4):

I just dig holes on either side of the crimson/corruption. If you have enough time, and a pickaxe good enough, then you could dig to the underworld and prevent the corruption/crimson from spreading in that direction.

Answer (score -6):

Start a new world, and use the Purification Powder on the corruption.