# What is the most efficient way to cleanse the corruption/crimson?

Tags: terraria

It’s been spreading for a while now and... I don’t know what to do. How can I cleanse it in the most efficient, easiest way?

Comment: Related: [How can I halt the spread of corruption after winning hell?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/how-can-i-halt-the-spread-of-corruption-after-winning-hell)

Comment: Also related: [How can I save the world from the spread of Hallow and Corruption/Crimson?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/how-can-i-save-the-world-from-the-spread-of-hallow-and-corruption-crimson)